# Error : [bool] query does not support [term]

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch version 2.3.2. I am trying to use filter on boolean query, but I am getting an error:

```
"type": "query_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "[bool] query does not support [term]",
```

My elasticsearch query is:

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {
          "title": "white"
        }},
        {
          "match": {
            "newContent": "white"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "default_collection": "true"
        }
      }
      ,"term":{
        "wiki_collection": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure what the problem is. I might be missing something

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to move both `term` filters inside a `filter` array (and use POST instead of GET when sending a payload):

```
POST index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "white"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "newContent": "white"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "default_collection": "true"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "wiki_collection": "true"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```